# AzureDevops branch permissions settings

Tags: azure-devops, azure-security

I have checked the docs from Microsoft for [AzureDevops](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/branch-permissions?view=azure-devops) and I understand how to manage permissions for a branch.

What I would like to know is if a user is automatically added with **Edit Policies** permission to **Allow** as he creates the branch (assuming a normal user not admin, and he's not inheriting this permission) ?

If the answer to the above question is yes, then is there any case when a second user could be added to the list of branch permissions automatically ? without an administrator adding it explicitly ? I couldn't find this in the docs anywhere.

*picture from msdn

[image: branch permissions editing]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, for each branch's permission setting, you could directly manage that user's or create a group then add that consultancy in the group, manage the group's permission.

In other words, without adding it explicitly, the user B could also be added to a group. 
You just need to make sure that you are not part of any groups that have the complete privilege **Denied**.

In Azure DevOps, Deny trumps Allow.

Unless you're a member of the **Project Collection Administrators** group on your organization, membership in a group that explicitly **Denies** any permission will deny your permission, even if you are in another group that explicitly **Allows** you the permission and even if you as an individual user are granted **Allow** on that permission.

We usually add developer to Contributors.

---

For the Inheritance part, you could **turn on your inheritance** and **clear explicit** with single click for each branch which have explicit permissions.

[image]

[image]

After this, Contributors Group in other branches will totally inherit the permissions set by root path of your repo/workspace.  For example, if root path are Allow, your branches should be Allow(inherited), if it's Deny, your branches should be Deny(inherited).

If a permission isn't directly allowed or denied for a user, then it may be inherited in two ways.

- Users inherit permissions from the groups to which they belong. When

  a permission is allowed for a user directly or through membership in

  a group that has that permission, and it is denied, either directly

  or through group membership, the permission is denied.

  Members of **Project Collection Administrators** or **Team Foundation

  Administrators** retain any allowed permissions, even if they belong to

  other groups that deny those permissions.
- Object-level permissions that are assigned for nodes of a hierarchy -

  areas, iterations, version control folders, work item query folders -

  are inherited down the hierarchy. That is, a user's permissions that

  are set at area-1 are inherited by area-1/sub-area-1, if the same

  permission is not explicitly allowed or denied for area-1/sub-area-1.

  If a permission is set explicitly for an object, like

  area-1/sub-area-1, then the parent node is not inherited, regardless

  of whether it is denied or allowed. If it's not set, then the

  permissions for that node are inherited from the closest ancestor

  that has the permission explicitly set.

More details please take a look at our official tutorial here: [Inheritance and security groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/about-permissions?view=azure-devops#inheritance-and-security-groups)